# Navigation Tabs with Action Bar for my settings

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i'm kinda new to Android but, i'm creating an app that will use Tabs for navigation and i'm using ActionBarSherlock as a library to use FragmentsTabs. I create my tabs succesfully :) ! Here's how i did it:

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("HOW IT WORKS");
    tab2.setText("CURRENT POSITION");
    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    bar.addTab(tab1);
    bar.addTab(tab2);

}
```

And then i have my TabListener who handles the content replacements between tabs, that's working fine. But my QUESTION IS how can i add an OptionsMenu now that i have the tabs?? i understand that i'm adding the Tabs to the Action Bar, but i need to add an OptionMenu to the Settings of my app. So it would be something like this next example:

[Image of a Tab Navigation with OptionMenu at the top](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/movies.png)

As you can see, there's the tabs navigation but at the top you'll see the logo and the OptionsMenu, and i don't know how to do that with the Tabs already implemented, i tried to do it as the usual implementation of a OptionsMenu and add the `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` inside my Activity and there inflate my menu, but i'm recieving this errors:

```
- Cannot override the final method from SherlockFragmentActivity
- overrides 
 com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu
```

Here's an ScreenShot of how it looks the app so you can understand me.

[MyApp with tabs but i need to place the optionsMenu](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vogbw5eubqdjut2/qSUM4QN4h8#f%3astack.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The override error is probably because your import is for the standard Android Menu, and not the ABS one.

Check your imports to make sure your `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` is based on `com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu` (and NOT `android.view.MenuItem`).

Comment: Thans Sir !! It did work :) , i modify the imports, inside the method we have to use `getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
  return true;`

Instead of the `MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;`